# CSS: How can I add something before the value of an input?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS :after pseudo element on INPUT field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

Here is what I have that I am trying to use to style an input button:

```
.save:before, input[type="submit"]:before {content: "\2714";}
```

and here is the HTML that I am trying to style:

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Save" class="form-submit">
```

This works all other elements that are not input's, but is there a way to get it to work on the above code?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field here is the answer

Comment: @simoncereska I had seen that page. but the accepted answer does not seem to work, and the second answer seems to say it is not possible. Is there no way to do this with js?

Comment: I suggest to add some wrapper and set styles for it. Maybe there is some workaround with js, but I guess it would add some elements before/ after or even the same wrapper :) ( just my thoughts )

Comment: Not every accepted answer works for everyone, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No CSS, but Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, il = inputs.length; i < il; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'submit') {
    inputs[i].value = '\u2714 ' + inputs[i].value;
  }
}
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BqzVU/)